# Gradle how to run android app from command-line?

Tags: android, gradle, command-line

Gradle how to run android app from command line using device or emulator?

```
root/
root/app

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Could not find the run app task. Not test apk.

Comment: There is no built-in task to "run" the app. You can use `installDebug` or `installRelease` to install it, then run it from the device or emulator UI. Or, you can write a Gradle task that uses `adb shell am` to start some activity (or whatever you want to consider "run" to be).